# Extra Column after Using Polyline to Raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, raster-conversion

Does anyone know why there is an extra column in the resulting raster file (Raster2) after using the tool Polyline to Raster in ArcMap 10.2? I had imported the cell size and set the extent to be the same as another raster file (Raster1). In the end. Raster 2's cell size and number of rows is the same as Raster 1, but Raster2 has one extra column.

Comment: What is the extra column called?